# Nekohtml sometimes don't work in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I have written a groovy script to get screen shots from Apple APP Store, it works fine when I run it as a script. Then I put it in a grails service, and call it by a grails job, it works fine in most cases, but sometimes it fails to parse web page. For example, when I try to parse http://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/james-camerons-avatar-for/id369020727 , the code works fine as a script, but won't work as a grails service. Can anyone tell me why?
  Here's my code

```
def parsePage(url) {
def parser = new org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser()
parser.setFeature('http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces', false)
String text = NetUtil.getUrlContent(url)
def page = new XmlParser(parser).parseText(text)
def list = page.depthFirst()
println "list size = ${list.size()}"

String screenShots = ""
def data = list.IMG.grep { it.@alt?.contains('iPhone') }
data.each {screenShots += it.@src + ";"}
return screenShots
}
```

Comment: what 'fails' mean at this case? throws exception? returns null? returns invalid value? something else?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: there is no errors, it just did not parse the page, the list contains no parsed elements.